# MediaStream not connecting to MediaElement

Tags: reactjs, typescript, html5-video, react-hooks

The React code to create the Element looks like this:

```
export const VideoPage: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  const localVideoRef = useCallback((localVideo: HTMLMediaElement | null) => {
    if (localVideo) {
      startVideo(localVideo);
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <video ref={localVideoRef} playsInline></video>
    </>
  );
};
```

The function `startVideo()` is just:

```
export async function startVideo(localVideo: HTMLMediaElement) {
  const mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: false,
    video: true,
  });
  console.log("localVideo", localVideo);
  console.log("mediaStream", mediaStream);
  localVideo.srcObject = mediaStream;
}
```

When I load the page, the green light over the camera lights; the red "video" dot appears on the tab in the browser; the video element takes up a square in the center of the browser page.  The following is logged on the console:

```
localVideo <video playsinline>​</video>​
mediaStream MediaStream {id: "jTQifTT0vSfcBw7v6E6E9M81mpv7qVhRrTe2", active: true, onaddtrack: null, onremovetrack: null, onactive: null, …}
```

All exactly as I expected.  In fact, the only thing that I did not expect is that the video stream does not appear on screen.

I am at loss for how to debug this.  Everything looks normal, but it just does not work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This was not a deliberate "haha, that's a subtle point, I should post a question to StackOverflow and then answer it myself to show off."  I posted the question in genuine puzzlement, and literally 30 seconds later, the answer occurred to me.

I was originally working from a crude JavaScript demo — which worked — and had the line:

```
<video id="localVideo" autoplay playsinline></video>
```

When I was translating into Typescript and React, VSCode wouldn't accept `autoplay`.  It wouldn't accept `playsinline` either, until I corrected the case to `playsInline`.  I dropped the `autoplay`, whatever it was and forgot about it.

Anyway, the correct line in React/Typescript is, of course:

```
<video ref={localVideoRef} playsInline autoPlay></video>
```

(Only problem now is, when the camera turns on, the MediaElement shows video of a fool...)